# Why has my Canada Visitor Visa been refused? And what can I do about it?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani national. I applied for Canadian visitor visa 10 days ago and received a rejection today. The reasons given were:

> You have not satisfied me that you would leave Canada at the end of
>   your stay as a temporary resident. In reaching this decision, I
>   considered several factors, including:
>
> - Travel History
> - Family ties in Canada and country of residence

My travel history is very clean. I have travelled to the UK and Saudi Arabia several times over the past ten years and have never been refused a visa. I recently returned from the UK after completing my Masters and started working in Pakistan. I also have family ties in Canada. My sister and brother in law are permanent residents of Canada. Meeting my sister was the purpose of my visit. I have a stable job in Pakistan and a family business to run. I attached proof of my employment, family business, relationship with my sister, proof of her permanent residency with the application.

I am confused. I want to reapply but I am not sure if I can add any more documentation to support my case. I have a reason to come back, my travel history is clean, I have family in my country of residence and Canada.

Can anyone please advise me regarding this matter?

Comment: Working for the family business is not always proof that you will return, as it is fairly easy to falsify.  And to a consular official it could appear that your sister holds no loyalty to the family business since she left her home country, so they might wonder how loyal you would be.  Do you have family (wife and/or children), are you a care giver to a relative, these are things that show a need to return home.

Comment: By "family ties in Canada and country of residence" they probably mean that they consider it possible that you'll want to stay in Canada because your sister lives there. You ought to show family ties in *Pakistan* that are *stronger* than those to your sister in Canada.

Comment: "proof of her permanent residency" - that was your biggest mistake. Visiting a family member who is a permanent resident/citizen is a huge red flag. A simple tourist trip would have worked a lot better.

Comment: @JonathanReez Are we advocating lying on visa applications now? Or did I somehow misunderstand this comment?

Comment: @MichaelHampton lying by admission in this case could have maybe gotten him the visa. Doesn't mean you should do it, as they're likely to figure out anyway that the sister lives there (depending on how thorough a check they do).

Comment: @MichaelHampton no, but it's perfectly legal to organize an independent trip, book hotels, plan sightseeing, etc. And then visit the sister as part of that tourist trip. If the visa form doesn't ask about relatives in Canada, it should have worked out.

Comment: @jwenting no, I was wrong. Canada does ask about brothers and sisters, so OP couldn't get away without lying. The Schengen form only asks about parents and children.

Comment: @jwenting did you mean "lying by omission"?

Answer (score 10):

**Why has my Canada Visitor Visa been refused?**

Because an Immigration official was not satisfied:

> [that you would leave Canada at the end of your stay as a temporary resident](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81681/4995).

**what can I do about it?**

Nothing.

Per [Government of Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=422&top=16):

> There is no formal appeal process if your application for a temporary resident visa is refused.
>
> Should you wish to re-apply, you should do so only if your situation has changed substantively or you have significant new information to submit.